# Calculation of conditional probability

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability

A problem as following: (from Prob, statistics, and random processes for electric engineering, p.264)

---

[image]

---

If I want to find $P(Y\leq y \mid X=+1)$, it can be calculated as following: $P[N+1\leq y]$.
It is obvious. (As book did)

My question is why not:    $\dfrac{P(Y\leq y,X=+1)}{P(X=+1)}$.

How to make sure both of them equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{P(Y\leq y,X=+1)}{P(X=+1)}=\frac{P(Y\leq y|X=+1)\cdot P(X=+1)}{P(X=+1)}=P(Y\leq y|X=+1)=P(X+N\leq y|X=+1)=P(1+N\leq y)$$
In other words $P(Y\leq y,X=+1)=P(1+N\leq y)\cdot P(X=+1)$